# GE Front Load Washer Problems

Tags: washing-machine

Recently I’ve had issues with my front load washing machine GE model GFAN1000L not completing cycles and pausing multiple times throughout. After completing everything down below my machine now also is all messed up with the cycle times as compared to before and also all it does on any cycle is spin forward for 2 seconds, reverse 2 seconds then fills with minimal water and drain instantly. It stays in the draining cycle until I pause the cycle and then it stops.

Here’s what I’ve tried:

- Cleaning out filter at pump on bottom front of machine
- Resetting by turning off and unplugging machine for 30-60 seconds (and holding START/PAUSE button during unplugging one of those times)
- Put machine in TEST mode and performed all diagnostic tests (only ones that didn’t do anything were t08/t09/t12 (cold and hot water valve tests, dispenser motor/mechanism test - it just beeped and didn’t do anything when trying to enable those tests). However on other tests I was able to fill the drum up right to the overflow switch with water so its tough to think it’s my water valves)
- I’ve also cleaned out the inline filters coming from the cold and hot water into the machine. The hot water was plugged up with sediment (sandy material which we had issues with in the rest of the water line filters after our town connected to a brand new water line last year) but both filters are now unplugged of debris

I am at a loss and obviously with Christmas on Tuesday and today being Saturday I’m not likely to get anyone out anytime soon to take a look at this. My guess is that the control board has an issue but any input would be helpful until I can get a technician out.

Comment: It sounds like your circuit board is bypassing the wash cycle after the load detection has been initiated. I'd pull out the switch board and look for any black arching or burned fuses on the small components, burned fuses look like they got too hot and left a faded mark, also look for any blown out capacitors, that's what I'd do personally, I don't know what else it could be, if it is a component it's only a 1 to 3 dollar fix, but if you don't know about electrical components on logic boards then the board could cost you double-triple digits

Comment: Now you know the wash cycle isn't going to start if the front lid switch is broke right

Comment: Thanks I will check the circuit board first and see if I notice anything like that. And the front lid switch is in good shape so it shouldn’t be that.

Comment: How  do you measure a front lid switch?

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep, here's a good explanation better than I can write in a text @Jared https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uMgtPQwiF78